# How would you do a for loop on a timer?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

What's the best way to do something like this?

```
for a in b
   #do this thing
   #wait a second, then continue the loop
```

in js

```
var a, _i, _len;

for (_i = 0, _len = b.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  a = b[_i];
  //do this thing
  //wait a second, then continue the loop
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To process one item from a `for (i in b)` loop each second until you're done with the items, you can do it like this:

```
var list = [];
// accumulate list of items to operate on into an array
// that can be incremented through
for (var i in b) {
    list.push(i);
}

function next() {
    if (list.length > 0) {
        var item = list.shift();
        // do something with the next item here

        // do the next iteration one second later
        setTimeout(next, 1000);
    }
}
// start it
next();
```

Comment: I think this recursive approach provides a more accurate time between events then setting an interval and clearing it on completion, so I'll mark this the right answer. Thanks @jfriend00

Comment: @fancy - just for completeness, this isn't technically recursive.  The first call to `next()` is done before the `setTimeout()` fires and initiates the next call to `next()` so it's not really recursion.  But I understand your point.

Comment: What are the performance implications of calling `setTimeout` during each loop iteration?  Are there any, or is there no difference between using `setInterval`?

Comment: There's not much meaningful difference in this case.  Performance isn't relevant here because you're giving the computer a whole second before you want to do the next piece of work.  `setTimeout()` is more likely to have 1s from the end of the previous work to the start of the next work.  `setInterval()` is more likely to have 1s from the beginning of one iteration to the start of the next iteration - these two differ by the length of execution of an interval.  But, since the execution time of an interval is likely only a few ms, this difference is probably irrelevant.

Comment: No need to keep track of position: `list = b.slice(); setInterval (-> process list.shift()), 1000`

Answer (score 3):

I think this would work with JavaScript:

```
var b = [1, 2, 3];
var timer;
var i = 0;
function timerFunction() {
    // base case
    if (i >= b.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        return;
    }

    var element = b[i];

    // do stuff to b here

    i++;
}

// if you want to execute it right away
timerFunction();

// start the timer
timer = setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);
```

Comment: I think we should ignore the loop requirement as it seems the OP just wants to run a block of code every second.  s/he just doesn't know about `setInterval`.  I could be wrong, but that's what I got from the question.

Comment: I thought it was asking more specifically how to iterate a collection with one second intervals.

Comment: Thanks @helixed - good answer, see comment on jfriend00 answer.

Comment: Obviously not considering the accepted answer does what I proposed, except it provides a more thorough example.  It treats the collection as queue, popping an item off each time the function is called, the difference being that it uses `setTimeout` as to check if there are any more items to process.  Heck, you even removed the loop in an update.

Comment: @EdS. no, your answer is wrong, you make no note of processing each item in the loop.

Comment: @fancy: It is in its current form, but you were responding to my comment... which was correct.  You took the loop out... which is what I said to do.  So.... how was I wrong about the loop again?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a chunk of code that needs to run every ~1 second you can use `setInterval` and forget the loop.

```
setInterval(function() { 
    // do stuff 
    }, 1000);  // every second (or so... not real time, but close enough)
```

I believe that this accomplishes what you are asking for.  It seems as though you want to run the code in the loop every second, so this will do it.

Comment: It seems pretty clear from the question that there is a `for (i in b)` loop that is relevant to running the code every second, probably because each second they want to process a different item from that `for` loop.  I don't know why you think you can ignore that part of the question.

Comment: @jfriend00: Is it incredibly difficult to grab the next element in subsequent iterations? (that was rhetorical; of course it isn't).  I see what you're saying though, it may make things more complicated than it needs to be.  Really depends on what is going on in the code, which we cannot see.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yes, you're right about that, but you did exactly what I proposed in my comment... yet you're still arguing for whatever reason.  I admit this answer is not as good, I just didn't go back and edit as there were already correct answers (i.e., yours.)